# How do I write an SOQL query to get information from cousins and their parents?

Tags: soql

I've got a working SOQL query, but I need to obtain one new piece of data, and I can't figure out how to get to it.
I have these objects:  Account, Address, Interaction, Association

Account has as children: Address, Interaction, and Association.

Each Association has two parents, both Accounts (one is a person, the other is an organization), the relationship named To_Account__r and From_Account__r.  The Interaction has as a parent an Address.
I need to get fields from both Accounts, and all 3 addresses (the person, the organization, the interaction).

Previously, before I needed the organization address, I was using this query (abbreviated for clarity):

```
SELECT Name,
  (SELECT Address_r.City FROM Interaction__r),
  (SELECT City from Address_r),
  (SELECT To_Account__r.Name FROM Association__r)
FROM Account
```

I need to do this in a single query.  How do I get that third address?

Comment: Does Account have a lookup to a primary address?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why must it be in a single query? If there was a straight forward multi-query solution, would that be acceptable?

Comment: Is this data model accurate? https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2gui.png

Comment: David:  Account does not have a lookup to a primary address.  It can have multiple child addresses, and one of them is marked as preferred.

Comment: Mark:  Yes, the model looks correct.  It doesn't express some things, like one of the parents of the association is the same object as the parent of the interaction and that the two parents of the association are different objects.

Comment: It's not a strict requirement to do this in a single query, but the existing system is built around that.  Also, the salesforce db is remote, I don't want to be making a query for each of thousands of objects.  If I had to package it in two queries, that's acceptable but not ideal.